# auto start new pdf when end current pdf

Tags: command-line, scripts, pdf

For example:

I have `PDF folder` that consists of `PDF files`: `a.pdf`, `b.pdf`, `c.pdf`, etc...

I use a "PDF reader" application like `okular`.

```
$ okular a.pdf
$ # read to the end of a.pdf and close okular window
$ okular b.pdf
$ # read to the end of b.pdf and close okular window
$ okular c.pdf
$ # read to the end of c.pdf and close okular window
$ # okular ...
```

Or like this:

```
$ okular a.pdf b.pdf
$ # read to the end of a.pdf and switch to b.pdf, then close okular window of a.pdf
$ okular c.pdf
$ # read to the end of b.pdf and switch to c.pdf, then close okular window of b.pdf
$ okular ...
$ # read to the end of c.pdf and switch to ... , then close okular window of c.pdf
$ # okular ...
```

Comment: It would be easy to open 3 pdfs one after another `for i in a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf; do okular "$i"; done` but I'm not sure if it's even possible to detect that you reached the end of the document in Okular.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk That trick would work very well. When a user closes a PDF, the next one is automatically opened. With custom file manager actions, one could create a script that automatically creates such a bash look with the selected files. Nor file manager or document viewers (at least not Evince) natively offer such possibility.

Comment: @vanadium: yes, it would but I did not post an answer because I wonder what OP meant by `read to the end of a.pdf`. For me it looks like OP wants to close PDF viewer after reaching the end of the document.

Comment: At least your suggestion answers the question as asked in the title. It would be quite nonsensical to automatically close the file when the user arrives at the last page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the part in bold: "auto start new pdf **when end** current pdf"?